# c programming how do i read the bytes stored as little indian?

Tags: c, printing, byte, unsigned-integer

unsigned short num = 258;

//How can i read the byte value as on how this num 258 is getting store (by default is stored as litle indian right?) so the value should be something like this `[ 2, 1 ]`or `[0x02,0x01]` <- as litle endian
how do i printf it out?

Comment: `memcpy(char_array, &num, sizeof num);`. Then read the `char_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to an `unsigned char` can be used to read the byte representation of an object.

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&num;
int i;
for (i=0; i<sizeof num; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", p[i]);
}
```